# Closing Processes represented by CheckedItems in c#

Tags: c#, listview, process, checkbox, checked

I am wanting to close processes that a user selects in a ListView box in another form. the ListView box uses checkboxes for selecting which processes to close. Unfortunately, i dont know how to convert the checked processes into processes....any help?

```
public void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process[] prs = Process.GetProcesses();
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Process proces in prs)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proces.MainWindowTitle))
            listView1.Items.Add(proces.MainWindowTitle);
    }
    foreach (Process PRC in listView1.CheckedItems)
    {
        \\Idk what to put here.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to kill a process you either need it's name or process id, so change your above code that adds process to `ListView1` to some thing like this:

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] prs = Process.GetProcesses();
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Process proces in prs)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proces.MainWindowTitle))
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                    item.Tag = proces.Id; //it will be used to kill this process
                    item.Text = proces.MainWindowTitle;
                    listView1.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

Note the tag field, which we will use later to kill the selected process.. Now loop through all selected `ListViewItems`, get the corresponding process id from tag field and get the reference to the process using `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById`. This method returns an object of Process, which exposes a `Kill` method using which one can stop the process this object refers to.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem list in listView1.CheckedItems)
            {
                Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(list.Tag));
                if (p != null)
                    p.Kill();
            }
    }
```